# Cannot find the "[ WinButton ]" object's parent "[ Dialog ]" (class Dialog) in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

There is a Dialog that gets open when I click on an export button from WebBrowser. Using step generator, I was able to insert a line & that works fine however when I perform same action using descriptive, it throws below error. I've first verified that Dialog exists & then tried clicking on save button, but no luck .

> Cannot find the "[ WinButton ]" object's parent "[ Dialog ]" (class
>   Dialog). Verify that parent properties match an object currently
>   displayed in your application.
>
> Line (94): "dialog("text:=.*").dialog("regexpwndtitle:=Save
>   As","text:=Save
>   As").WinButton("text:=&Save","regexpwndtitle:=&Save").highlight".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Browser("title:=.*").Dialog("text:=.*").WinButton("regexpwndtitle:=.*Save.*").Click ?

Comment: Your line would just work fine for the first dialog that opens..the problem lies with save as button.. You can relate this to save as button when you try to save a file from an explorer window